in the python ibis framework, Is there a way to cumsum over a order by column
I have a very large complex ibis script with a portion calculating some columns. at the end, I need to ibis.to_sql(t) to get a sql statement for my python. So I can't use pandas
lets say i have this table
import ibis 
from ibis import _ 
ibis.options.interactive = True 
t = ibis.memtable( { "fruit": ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange"], 
"price": [0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33], "order": [1, 2, 3, 4], } )

is there a way to output
┏━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ fruit ┃ price ┃ order ┃cumsum_price│
┡━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
│ string │ float64 │ int64 │ int64   │
├────────┼─────────━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
│ apple  │ 0.50    │ 1     │ 0.50    │
│ apple  │ 0.50    │ 2     │ 1.0     │
│ banana │ 0.25    │ 3     │ 1.25    │
│ orange │ 0.33    │ 4     │ 1.58    │
└────────┴─────────━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

I attempted something like this
t =  t.mutate(cumsum_price = t['price']+t.cumsum_price.lag().over(order_by=[t.order])

Which does not work.
Again, i cannot use pandas, I need to use Ibis to output sql

You may use the cumsum function like this:
    import ibis 
    from ibis import _ 
    ibis.set_backend("pyspark")
    ibis.options.interactive = True 
    t = ibis.memtable( { "fruit": ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange"], "price": [0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33], "order": [1, 2, 3, 4], } )
    t = t.mutate(cumsum_price = t.price.cumsum().over(order_by=[t.order]))
    ibis.to_sql(t)

┏━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ fruit  ┃ price   ┃ order ┃ cumsum_price ┃
┡━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ string │ float64 │ int64 │ float64      │
├────────┼─────────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│ apple  │    0.50 │     1 │         0.50 │
│ apple  │    0.50 │     2 │         1.00 │
│ banana │    0.25 │     3 │         1.25 │
│ orange │    0.33 │     4 │         1.58 │
└────────┴─────────┴───────┴──────────────┘

SELECT
  "t0"."fruit",
  "t0"."price",
  "t0"."order",
  SUM("t0"."price") OVER (ORDER BY "t0"."order" ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CAST(0 AS TINYINT) following) AS "cumsum_price"
FROM "ibis_pandas_memtable_5pr6er42fvadvct5a42v7u6cai" AS "t0"

